# OR operator slowing down MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have four tables each relating to the others by some fields: `games, teams, altnames, countries`.

Wrote this query with an OR operator in an ON clause (see line 6) which slows down the query very much:

```
select ROUND(AVG(attendance)), competition, team1, countries.* from games 
LEFT JOIN (teams 
    INNER JOIN countries ON ( countries.iso3 = teams.country ) 
    LEFT JOIN altnames ON ( altnames.entityType = "team" AND altnames.season = "1011" AND altnames.entityId = teams.longName )  
) 
ON ( altnames.altValue = games.team1 OR teams.longName = games.team1 )
where games.season="1011" group by games.competition, games.team1 having AVG(attendance)>= 500 order by AVG(attendance) desc
```

Query is fast enough when not using the OR, only one of the two conditions at a time:

1.

```
select ROUND(AVG(attendance)), competition, team1, countries.* from games 
LEFT JOIN (teams 
    INNER JOIN countries ON ( countries.iso3 = teams.country ) 
    LEFT JOIN altnames ON ( altnames.entityType = "team" AND altnames.season = "1011" AND altnames.entityId = teams.longName )  
) 
ON ( altnames.altValue = games.team1 )
where games.season="1011" group by games.competition, games.team1 having AVG(attendance)>= 500 order by AVG(attendance) desc
```

2.

```
select ROUND(AVG(attendance)), competition, team1, countries.* from games 
LEFT JOIN (teams 
    INNER JOIN countries ON ( countries.iso3 = teams.country ) 
    LEFT JOIN altnames ON ( altnames.entityType = "team" AND altnames.season = "1011" AND altnames.entityId = teams.longName )  
) 
ON ( teams.longName = games.team1 )
where games.season="1011" group by games.competition, games.team1 having AVG(attendance)>= 500 order by AVG(attendance) desc
```

Any idea why is this happening, and how the first query can be speed up?

---

EDIT:

Here are the tables:

altnames:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `altnames` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `entityType` enum('team','comp','logo') NOT NULL,
  `entityId` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `season` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `altValue` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `entityType_season_altValue` (`entityType`,`season`,`altValue`)
)
```

countries:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `countries` (
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `iso2` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `iso3` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `color` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  KEY `iso3` (`iso3`)
)
```

games:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `games` (
  `id` int(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `competition` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `season` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `stage` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gamedate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `team1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `team2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `score1` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `score2` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attendance` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `source` varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
  `altsource` varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
  `note` varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `competition_season` (`competition`,`season`),
  KEY `team_comp_season` (`team1`,`competition`,`season`)
)
```

teams:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `teams` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `shortName` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `urlSlug` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NSP',
  `competitions` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` float(10,6) DEFAULT '0.000000',
  `longitude` float(10,6) DEFAULT '0.000000',
  `inactive` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `long` (`longName`),
  KEY `FK_teams_countries` (`country`),
  CONSTRAINT `teams_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`country`) REFERENCES `countries` (`iso3`)
)
```

Comment: Use **`EXPLAIN`** to see the execution plan. Most likely, the `OR` is on conditions on two different columns, and that means that MySQL isn't making efficient use of index. Sometimes we can get better performance by combining results from two efficient queries with a `UNION ALL` set operator.

Comment: Which table is `attendance` from? You should use table prefixes for every column, so we don't need to guess. You should also post the schema and describe the relations between the tables when they are not obvious and can't be derived from column names.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel attendance is a field in games, not a table. Similarly competition and team1 too.

Comment: @spencer7593 Unfortunately I'm not sure how should I interpret EXPLAIN: https://i.imgur.com/IYGK7d6.png

Comment: Have you looked at the relevant MySQL documentation? Alternatively I would try bypassing the problem using a UNION (with appropriate de-duplication).

Answer (score -2):

I just had a funny idea in mind While waiting for an expert opinion,
Try to switch OR operator with AND.

**conditionA OR conditionB**

is equivalent to

**NOT(NOT(conditionA) and NOT(conditionB))**

Good Luck,

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not clear why this would help, could you edit the answer to provide more information please.

Comment: Tried it. Still very slow.